# jQuery: Only transition if it's in certain browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/uhmubhtf/3/

I want to apply jQuery only if the browser width is certain length but also detect it's not already in it.

Right now, it applies it regardless because it's constantly checking the browser width and applying the fadeIn and fadeOut.

```js
$(function(){
  function screenClass() {
  
 if ($( window ).width() <500){
$(".ok span").fadeOut(function(){
$(this).html("no").fadeIn();
});
}
else{

$(".ok span").fadeOut(function(){
$(this).html("yes").fadeIn();
});
}

  }
  $(window).bind('resize',function(){
  screenClass();
  });
  
  
  });
```

```css
.ok{
  background:blue;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  transition:1s;
  font-size:30px;
  color:white;
}
.span{
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok"><span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted?  You would need to just add conditions...

```
$(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 500) {
    $('.ok span').html("yes");
  } else {
    $('.ok span').html("no");
  }

  function screenClass() {
    if ($(window).width() < 500 && $('.ok span').html() == 'yes') {
      $(".ok span").fadeOut(function() {
        $('.ok span').html("no").fadeIn();
      });
    } else if ($(window).width() > 500 && $('.ok span').html() == 'no') {
      $(".ok span").fadeOut(function() {
        $(".ok span").html("yes").fadeIn();
      });
    }

  }
  $(window).bind('resize', function() {
    screenClass();
  });


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chqzeshj/

Comment: **@utxin**: Your code is nearly perfect but in `} else if  ($(window).width()` is not  `> 500` but `>= 500`.  for `$(".ok span").html("no").fadeIn();` is better: `$(this).html("no").fadeIn();`. Same thing for `$(".ok span").html("no").fadeIn();` use instead `$(this).html("yes").fadeIn();`.

Comment: Thanks!  Whipped it up rather hurriedly :)